# Are any of the following considered properties? If so, what kind of properties are they?

Tags: ontology, properties

Suppose Archie is the tallest man in Antarctica. Can Archie be said to have the property of being the tallest man in Antarctica?

Now suppose Archie tries to lift a crate of penguin eggs and finds it heavy. Can Archie legitimately claim that the crate has the property of being heavy (in the sense that it's heavy for him)?

What if we took something more abstract? If object A shares each of its intrinsic visual properties with at least one other object in set S, can A be said to have the property of having no unique intrinsic visual properties in set S? If so, can this property of A be considered a visual property (since the basis for its determination is visual, rather than, say aural or gustatory)?

If any of the above is correct, what kind of properties are these? Clearly they are different from the property of being green, or the property of having a mass of 5kg, because they are context-dependent. If those aren't properties at all, what are they?